# JavaScript simple parameter error

Tags: javascript

```
function moveDoi(n) {
        var delay = -1;
        var left = document.getElementById("One");         
        var currentLeft = parseInt(getComputedStyle(left).left, 10);
        setTimeout(move, delay);
        function move(){
          if (currentLeft <= n ) {            
            currentLeft+=3;            
            left.style.left = currentLeft + "px";            
            setTimeout(move, delay);       
          }
        }
      };
```

In this code I have `n` as a parameter of the function, that is used in the `if` conditional statement.
For this function i need to have one more parameter `x` that will change the `"One"` so i need to obtain something like this: `document.getElementById(""+x+"")` . However, this is not working?

How can I add one more parameter to the function that needs to be in  quotes (" ") in function?

Comment: since your `x` will be a string, you need not put it inside another set of quotes. Simply use `document.getElementbyId(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass `x` into the function.  Then, you simply need to reference it when calling `document.getElementById`.  There are is no need to append/prepend quotes, since `x` is already a string.

```
function moveDoi(n, x) {
        var delay = -1;
        var left = document.getElementById(x);         
        var currentLeft = parseInt(getComputedStyle(left).left, 10);
        setTimeout(move, delay);
        function move(){
          if (currentLeft <= n ) {            
            currentLeft+=3;            
            left.style.left = currentLeft + "px";            
            setTimeout(move, delay);       
          }
        }
      };
```

Comment: Can you add comments to explain what the OP was doing wrong, what should he have done instead?

Comment: much better. Adding comments helps them not make the same mistake again.